# Sitecore CM/CD/SQL IOPS Guidelines

Tags: azure, sql-database

When looking at whether Azure premium storage is necessary, IOPS (input/output operations per second) is a good metric/guideline to look at. Does Sitecore provide any recommendations/guidelines as to what range is recommended for content management, content delivery and SQL Servers? Sitecore does provide guidance for Mongo servers, as they are known for needing specific IOP levels. I am looking for specific numbers for the other server roles.

Comment: Sitecore's doc site only seems to provide suggested hardware specifications as far as I've seen, nothing in terms of IOPS. On a related note this article by kamsar is quite useful: http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/07/Sitecore-Azure-Role-Sizing-Guide/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB disk IOPS](http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/mongodb-disk-iops)

Comment: I reached out to Sitecore support for their opinion. Their official position is that they don't have one.

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware any IOPS guidelines, but there is a [Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2 Performance White Paper](https://doc.sitecore.net/~/media/2F3A6E768BEF4100BE934CF74CAD176F.ashx) where they have made many test and the Premium Storage Account is only mentioned for MongoDB.

In general, your Primary MongoDB takes the biggest hit and needs the fastest drives. Other than that, Sitecore solutions have largely been found to be CPU bound, rather than bound by performance of drives and storage systems.

Comment: Please provide more info in the answer as this is a link-only answer now...

Comment: in my answer I think I covered the most important thing from the document, that the Premium Storage Account is needed only for the the Mongo DB.

Comment: Links are not forever though. I agree with @Gatogordo's assessment. See also http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: I think, after edits, this answer is within our guidelines